# populating drop down box in mvc with list

Tags: model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

here my controller code

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<dropdown> lobj = new List<dropdown>();
            //DataLayer.DbOperation dob = new DataLayer.DbOperation();
            data.db odb = new data.db();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = odb.LoadGrid();
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)//adding data to the List from Data set
            {
                lobj.Add(new dropdown
                {
                    data = dr["city"].ToString()    
                });

                ViewBag.city = new SelectList(lobj);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

and this is my view page code

```
            @Html.DropDownList("city")
```

its shows six times "mvc.models.dropdownlist" names in dropdown 
 but not show the city names
 pls help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are creating anonymous type which is not read properly by View.

Try this:

```
lobj.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Value = dr["city"].ToString(),
    Text = dr["city"].ToString() 
});
```

(This is a classical problem, must be a duplicate, but I can't find the exact match)